# Angular Version Update Not Reflected

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npx

I've been following this Angular guide (https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=8.2-12.0) to upgrade the Angular version of my project from 9 to 10 (12 ultimately) but when I execute `ng --version` command it still shows 9.1.13.

I have provided links to two images. The first one showing the update from Angular version 9 to 10 and the second showing the current Angular version of the project.

[Upgrade Angular Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5DU1.jpg)

[Current Angular Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPUmi.png)

Anyone know what may be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running `ng --version` command outside of your project folder and you have global @angular/cli installed on your machine, so maybe it's normal.

You can have a specific @angular/cli version installed for your project and another global installed on your PC.

Try to run `npm i -g @angular/cli@12.2.18` and then run your `ng --version`

It will install a global @angular/cli@12.2.18 on your PC. No matter on witch folder you are.